# Warning: No message defined for emailAddress

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate for validations. I am having the problem where i am validating fields in which i enter special characters.

The validation scripts that are getting formed are:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        IDM.validationRules["emailAddress"]=  
{ required : true , emailAdd : true }; IDM.validationMsgs["emailAddress"]=  
{ required : 'Email Address is required' , emailAdd : 'should be in email format' };
</script>
```

Now, when i enter abc in the email input field i get error message should be in email format while if i enter any valid email id as soon as any special characters like "@" or "." are keyed in the function emailAdd never gets called and i am thrown an error message
**Warning: No message defined for emailAddress**

Similar thing is happening for date field i.e. after "/" is entered similar message for date field is also thrown.

PS: All other validations are working fine.

Comment: Isn't it a server side (PHP) warning?

Comment: No it is not, the warning is coming from jquery.validate.js file. Moreover, i am not using PHP. I am working on CQ5 cms. After some investigation i found that this message is thrown when you have a custom rule and corresponding message is missing but in my case i have custom rule and message both the only problem is that my custom message is not getting called once i key in special characters.

Comment: @SamThadhani - I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution to this?